# ViewPager not showing custom views

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

as the title says the ViewPager isn't showing the content it is supposed to. I have looked all over for solutions, but none of them worked. Maybe you guys can help me out. Thanks in advance!

I want to add custom views dynamically to the adapter, because the views are made async with data from a database.

The custom PagerAdapter

```
public class SlidePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<CardView> mCards;

    public SlidePagerAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mCards = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mCards.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition (Object object) {
        int index = mCards.indexOf(object);
        if (index == -1)
            return POSITION_NONE;
        else
            return index;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View v = mCards.get(position);
        container.addView(v);
        return container;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem (ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView(mCards.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    public void add(Card card) {
        mCards.add(new CardView(mContext, card));
    }

    public void addAll(List<Card> cards) {
        for (Card card : cards) {
            add(card);
        }
    }

    public void clear() {
        mShopcards.clear();
    }
}
```

**The custom views are made and saved in the list in the adapter successfully, but they don't show up in the ViewPager...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

```
@Override 
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) { 
return view == object; 
}
```

You cannot compare the 2. view is the child of object.

```
    @Override 
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) { 
View v = mShopcards.get(position);
 container.addView(v);
 return container;
 }
```